# Android Repository export project plus all dependencies

Tags: android

I imported an Android App from the Android Repository to my eclipse and I am seeing that they are many references to classes that cannot be resolved. Is there a way to checkout automatically all dependencies of the project? My intention is to make an own version of the APK, is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check the libs folder in project directory,if the jar files required are present, just right click on you project->properties->java build path and add the libraries